# How many channels I can have with NATS Streaming server?

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

I'm looking for a streaming server and the docs on NATS Streaming don't make it clear what scaling strategy will be possible with it in my case.

I assume we'll be using [FT mode](https://docs.nats.io/nats-streaming-concepts/ft) since we need to ensure best message durability, but that means the whole set of channels will be handled by only one server at a time.

It is also possible to [partition channels](https://docs.nats.io/nats-streaming-concepts/partitioning), thus allowing multiple server FT groups to coexist in a single mesh and split the set of channels between different servers.

What is not clear however is the following.

If I chose the application model where every single entity receives a dedicated unique channel, and I can have millions of coexisting entities (e.g. active customers) - will NATS be able to handle millions of channels at once, in FT+Partitioning mode?

There likely will be only one publisher and consumer per channel in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Having millions of active consumers (corresponding to unique channels) is a stretch that I am not sure NATS Streaming or the system it is running on will be able to handle. Note that a channel is represented on disk by a directory and that directory then contains files for messages (data + index) and for the subscriptions state on this channel. So you may run into file descriptor issues.

Not clear from your question if the consumers are 1 for each channel, but if not and you possibly have a high number of consumers for the same channel, then you need to think also about fan-out issues where a message has to be delivered (TCP sent) to that many consumers.

Comment: It's likely will be one consumer per channel, clarified that in the question.

Also, I'm expecting to back it by SQL, so file descriptors should not be a problem. Or will some tmp files be created even if the state is in SQL?